How can I render the below model in tree structure and bind it to form?
I do have an assessment model having n- number of child assessment models. I want to render AssessmentNode models as form elements (for ex: TextBox HTML element) in a tree structure. A form can have many assessment node elements.
I have used the LIFO Stack class to render the model in UI. I am looking to bind the poped node into Form.
public class Assessment
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AssessmentNode> Nodes { get; set; }
    public List<Connector> Connectors { get; set; }
}
public class AssessmentNode
{
    public Guid NodeID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public bool HasChildNode { get; set; }
}

public class Connector
{
    public Guid ConnectorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SourceNodeId { get; set; }
    public string TargetNodeId { get; set; }
}

How can I render the nodes into tree structure in UI and bind it to form?
For example:

Q1
Q2
a) 2Qa
b) 2Qb
Q3


How does the data structure you show produce the example you post?  And is the end result of this supposed to be HTML?  Is this a report, or are you looking for input from the user?

I have manually mapped the assessment questions into the above model. Yes, end result is HTML form elements with Question as title and answer property bind to the HTML input elements.

The use of a Connector does not enforce that it's a Tree. It could be any kind of Graph.  The naming (Source & Target) doesn't help. HasChildNode ought to be redundant.

Is your model fixed or can you redesign it?

It is not fixed yet.
